# Change figure legend text

Tags: matlab, legend, matlab-figure

I have a figure with several lines and a corresponding legend. For example:

```
figure; hold all; 
plot(sin(1:0.1:10)); 
plot(cos(1:0.1:10)); 
legend('sin', 'cos');
```

I wonder if it is possible to change a text of a specific legend entry. If I do

```
hline = findobj(gcf, 'type', 'line');
legend(hline(5), 'new text')
```

the old legend disappears and a new one appears with just a single entry. How can I keep the whole legend and only change one entry?

Comment: Why not simply assign it by `legend('sin', 'new text');`?

Comment: @herohuyongtao: Because I want to change an existing legend. So I need to get it from the figure somehow first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, take a handle when you create the figure, or alternatively, extract the legend handle from the current figure:

```
h1 = legend('sin', 'cos');
h1 = findobj(gcf, 'tag', 'legend');
```

You can then retrieve the current text:

```
ltext = get(h1,'string');
```

`ltext` is a cell array of strings.  Simply replace the one you want (presuming you know which number in the legend it is):

```
ltext{n} = 'new text';
set(h1,'string',ltext);
```

Comment: Just what I wanted. Thanks!